# How to install Liquidsoap & Airtime on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, software-installation, repository, broadcast

That's the question, I already try some tutorials but I don't get any one to works

What repositories are needed? Is there any repo than I can add than have it to install it directly? Is there any way to avoid using Debian Box?

I want to keep the server without graphic interphase, although the webinterphase of Airtime is acceptable.

I'm trying to use it to Broadcast music from an external hard disk, to transmit when the DJ's will not be on air, like an AutoDj function

I'm using icecast for the server, I do some test and it works, but I want to automatize it and then I must add liquidsoap and/or airtime for this.

This is the link to the page of the aplication http://savonet.sourceforge.net/

Any help?

PS: Any suggestion of another software to do this than will be actualy supported would be very welcome.

PS2: If you think I can receive a better answer in another Stack Exchange place, or think you know a forum, or a place/tutorial that can work, please let me know ;)

I already try IRC, btw.

PS3: I'm asking this here because in the "Amateur Radio" Stack there are not so many online radio questions & because someone there put a doubt about if that was the place to post it, which I'm not sure if is or not. There is a Linux-Software question too, I want it to ask it here.

Comment: Please include links to the software you are talking about so we can check it out without having to look for it.

Comment: @terdon i added the link editing the post, here is btw http://savonet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214064/how-to-install-liquidsoap-airtime-on-centos-6-5